# Join cells and headers value in a row with Google Sheets filtering blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I would like to know how to filter and join each row adding the header before the values addin a ":" beetween Header and Value and separating them with ";". If the value is blank the header don't have to be selected.

<kbd><kbd>Gender


<kbd>Female</kbd>
<kbd>Man</kbd></kbd>

<kbd>Category

<kbd>XYZ</kbd>

<kbd>ABC</kbd></kbd>

<kbd>Weight

<kbd>45</kbd>

<kbd>30</kbd></kbd>

<kbd>Elasticity

<kbd>High</kbd>
<kbd>Medium</kbd></kbd></kbd>

The result need to be:

<kbd>Features

<kbd>Category:XYZ;Weight:45;Elasticity:High</kbd>

<kbd>Gender:Female;Elasticity:Medium</kbd>

<kbd>Gender:Male;Category:ABC;Weigh:30</kbd></kbd>

I'm playing with arrayformula, join and filter functions but I can't figured out how to "loop" to join header with values, maybe I simply don't know what function I have to use.

(If possibile I would like to avoid the use of Google Script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the upper-left corner of a sheet, the following works (linebreaks added for readability):

```
=arrayformula(
  regexreplace(
   regexreplace(
    if(len(A2:A), A1 & ":" & A2:A, "") 
     & ";" & 
    if(len(B2:B), B1 & ":" & B2:B, "") 
     & ";" & 
    if(len(C2:C), C1 & ":" & C2:C, ""), 
   ";+", ";"), 
  "^;|;$", "")
 )
```

Each `if` processes one column of data, prepending values by headers if the value is nonempty. The `;` are inserted in between.

The `regexreplace` perform a cleanup. The first one replaces any sequence of semicolons by a single semicolon. The second removes the semicolon at the beginning or end of string.

Although it's tempting to try `join(";", ...)` here (which wouldn't require the cleanup), it can't handle a two-dimensional array of data.

Comment: worked replacing commas with semicolon. ;-)  is there a solution without having to copy and past every "if"?

Comment: I don't know of a solution without multiple `if`.  Yes, if your locale uses commas for decimal separators, then semicolons separate the arguments of a function. Where a decimal dot is used, the arguments are separated by commas. Something to keep in mind when reading questions and answers on this site, with users from around the world.